# Quickest and most reliable way to get clips of h.264 video from VLC saved uncompressed

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc, codec, transcode, handbrake

I am trying to set up a pipeline to record video clips while I watch movies (usually but not always in h.264) and prepare them for editing in Premier. I usually watch videos using VLC, and the "record" button is perfect. However, in order to edit the video, it needs to be in a format other than h.264.

I've had variable luck with transcoding.. it seems that I have to use trial and error to find a codec I can convert to that doesn't result in horrible artifacts. I'm thinking it would be best to decode the video and save in an uncompressed format, then edit, and then encode in the codec of my choice.

Is there a way for ffmpeg/handbrake to decompress video and then save the uncompressed video instead of transcoding to a different codec? Or better yet, to get VLC's "record" button to save the decoded stream instead of the encoded video?

Comment: Why not load the video you are watching into Premiere?

Comment: Because I don't use Premier as my video player and the point is to capture clips as I am watching movies.

Comment: Premiere should be able to edit H.264 video. What exactly is wrong with the output from VLC using the record button?

Comment: Premier does not handle H.264 video well.

Answer (score 0):

Uncompressed is huge. A 1 minute 25 fps 1080p video will be ~4.4 G. It seems like you want an intermediate format. UT video is a free, open source, lossless compressed format that is editor friendly, can be supported by Premiere, and is supported by `ffmpeg`.

Example `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v utvideo -c:a pcm_s16le output.avi
```

To get support in Premiere, close premiere, [download](http://umezawa.dyndns.info/archive/utvideo/?C=M;O=D) and install UT video, and then start Premiere.

As for the VLC record button I believe it simply remuxes, so it does no re-encoding to other formats. I'm not sure if the behavior can be changed but I didn't really look into it.